# Why is rsync prompting for password in bash script, but runs fine when executed outside of script?

Tags: bash, rsync

I have a shared SSH keys with another server so I can login without a password. Executing:

```
rsync -avze ssh --blocking-io --delete --rsh='ssh -p2020' user@XXX.XX.XXX.XX:/foo/* /bar/;
```

Runs fine. No password prompt. But that command in a bash file:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
rsync -avze ssh --blocking-io --delete --rsh='ssh -p2020' user@XXX.XX.XXX.XX:/foo/* /bar/;
```

Run like so:

```
sudo ./copyfiles.sh
```

Gives me this:

```
user@XXX.XX.XXX.XX's password:
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Your roots ~/.ssh/ folder does not contain the private key you are using to authenticate on the server.

Comment: what happens when you run `sudo rsync -avze ssh --blocking-io --delete --rsh='ssh -p2020' user@XXX.XX.XXX.XX:/foo/* /bar/;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be running the script as root (`sudo`) but run the command line as some other user (this is just a guess). Most likely, the public key of the root user is not present on the destination machine.

Comment: Checked this, not the case either :(

Comment: Hmmmm. Maybe you are right. When I execute the rsync command prefixed with sudo then I get prompted. But both root and user ssh keys have been copied over :/

Comment: Is the root key copied under /home/user/.ssh on the destination machine ? Because that seems to be the user you're connecting as.

Comment: Also, the remote machine much allow root to use key authentication.

Comment: The simplest check would be to try to ssh on that machine as root: `sudo su -` and then `ssh user@XXX.XX.XXX.XX`

Comment: Thanks guys, Costi got it right. I thought i had cat the key over but the key didn't exist in the first place so it copied over nothing. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo` program is probably creating a new shell without some SSH environment variables.

Try

```
sudo -E ./copyfiles.sh
```